# How do I export a base64 image to excel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg

I am looking for a way to Export Excel Charts from NVd3 in Angularjs.

I am trying code like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71kswzno/))

```
<button id="myButtonControlID">Export Table data into Excel</button>
<div id="divTableDataHolder">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src='http://codepattern.net/Blog/pics/CodepatternLogoN.png' alt=''/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="img" src='' alt=''/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("img").src ="data:image/png;base64,..."
```

Comment: Are you sure the intention is to put an image into an excel file? This seems to be an incorrect interpretation of a spec.

Comment: Yes, my intention was put an nvd3 graph into excel,but I don't exact solution for doing that, so I try to convert svg format data to base64 type image and try to put an image into excel.I f you have any idea please share with me(export svg to excel).

Comment: I also need an answer to this question as I want my base64 image to be exported into excel using javascript or jquery. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Please research on https://gist.github.com/umidjons/352da2a4209691d425d4

Comment: If you're using office 365 (with subscription) you can directly import the svg after downloading from the website. If you're using an older version, you can always export the image as a png and then read it into excel

Comment: Could you please answer the following three questions? 1) Which are the versions of Excel a possible solution must be compatible with? 2) Is this for a known audience who you can tell to configure their browsers to open a certain mime type with a certain application, or is this for every user on the 'net? 3) Do you want to embed that chart into an existing Excel file, or would it be sufficient to open a new Excel file which only contains that chart?

Answer (score -1):

Excel doesn't seem to like base64 encoded images...

Try simply doing a ajax POST request to your server with the PNG base64 encoded data of the currently failing image, into a service which stores images and provides hosting for them, some example php code (I'm assuming you have access to a linux server that can run php):

```
<?php
$somecode = unique_name(); //left as excersise for the reader.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],"destination_$somecode.png");
//also, check for errors.
echo $somecode;
```

Then simply use the server's response as the URL in the excel file.
that way you can embed a *link* to an image instead of an image itself.

so the cell contents could me similar to:

```
<td><img src='yourhost.com/your_image_location' /></td>
```

Smaller excel files should make people happy, but 
You'll have to consider things like how long the files will live there
consider including the actual data that was used to generate the form, so future excel users can rebuild the graph inexpensively if the image server goes down, or the images "expire".

I Hope this helps!